# Sitemesh take place of whole view spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I'm using sitemess in my spring mvc project. Please look at my code first.

decorator.xml

```
<decorator name="main-layout" page="main-layout.jsp">
    <pattern>/products</pattern>
    <pattern>/welcome</pattern>
    <pattern>/admin</pattern>
    <pattern>/ajax</pattern>
</decorator>
```

web.xml

```
<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!--  Sitemesh: Decorates pages with layouts  -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In my main-layout I just import a navbar. The problem is **it's only show the main-layout**(only navbar is showed) for every view of my site.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one decorator defined so it is logical that only that layout would be applied for every page, you need to define other layout in your decorator.xml

Typically this is how my decorator.xml looks like

```
 <decorator name="main" page="outer.jsp">
        <pattern>*/public/login*</pattern>
</decorator>
        
<decorator name="default" page="default.jsp">
        <pattern>*app*</pattern>
</decorator>
```

Also make sure that you have `<decorator:body/>` in every layout file, this is the placeholder where content from inner pages would be displayed.

Something like this

```
<body>
   <nav></nav>
   <aside></aside>
   <decorator:body/>
</body>
```

Comment: I have created the similar pages with the different directories. but Sitemesh is not working instead it take from the mail layout file. What may be the issues ? `<decorators defaultdir="/Page/Decorators">
    <excludes>
        <!-- Exclude the specific page from the decorator -->
        <pattern>/index.jsp</pattern>        
    </excludes>    
    <decorator name="user" page="layoutUser.jsp">
        <pattern>*/User/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
    <decorator name="main" page="layoutMain.jsp">
        <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>`